# How does Dataloader cache and batch database requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dataloader

Looking at the [DataLoader library](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader), how is it caching and batching requests?

The instructions specify usage in the following way:

```
var DataLoader = require('dataloader')

var userLoader = new DataLoader(keys => myBatchGetUsers(keys));

userLoader.load(1)
    .then(user => userLoader.load(user.invitedByID))
    .then(invitedBy => console.log(`User 1 was invited by ${invitedBy}`));

// Elsewhere in your application
userLoader.load(2)
    .then(user => userLoader.load(user.lastInvitedID))
    .then(lastInvited => console.log(`User 2 last invited ${lastInvited}`));
```

But I am unclear how the `load` function is working, and what the `myBatchGetUsers` function might look like. Please can you provide me an example if possible!

Answer (score 4):

The DataLoader utility from Facebook works by combining input requests with a batch function that *you have to provide*. It only works with requests that use `Identifiers`.

There are three phases:

1. Aggregation phase : Any request on the `Loader` object is delayed until `process.nextTick`
2. Batch phase : The `Loader` just call the `myBatchGetUsers` function you have provided with the combination of all requested Keys.
3. Split phase : the result is then 'split' so input requests get the desired part of the response.

That's why in your provided example you should have only two requests:

- One for Users 1 and 2
- Then one for related users (`invitedByID`)

To implement this with mongodb for example, you should just define the myBatchGetUsers function to use the `find` method appropriately:

```
function myBatchGetUsers(keys) {
    // usersCollection is a promisified mongodb collection
    return usersCollection.find(
       {
          _id: { $in: keys }
       }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it helpful to recreate the part of `dataloader` that I use, to see one possible way that it could be implemented. (in my case I only use the `.load()` function)

So, creating a new instance of the `DataLoader` constructor gives you 2 things:

1. A list of identifiers (empty to begin with)
2. A function that uses this list of identifiers to query the the database (you provide this).

The constructor could look something like this:

```
function DataLoader (_batchLoadingFn) {
  this._keys = []
  this._batchLoadingFn = _batchLoadingFn
}
```

And instances of the `DataLoader` constructor have access to a `.load()` function, which needs to be able to access the `_keys` property. So it's defined on the `DataLoad.prototype` object:

```
DataLoader.prototype.load = function(key) {
   // this._keys references the array defined in the constructor function
}
```

When creating a new object via the DataLoader constructor (`new DataLoader(fn)`), the `fn` you pass it needs to fetch data from somewhere, taking an array of keys as arguments, and return a promise that resolves to an array of values that corresponds to the initial array of keys.

For example, here is a dummy function that takes an array of keys, and passes the same array back but with the values doubled:

```
const batchLoadingFn = keys => new Promise( resolve => resolve(keys.map(k => k * 2)) )
```

```
keys: [1,2,3]
vals: [2,4,6]

keys[0] corresponds to vals[0]
keys[1] corresponds to vals[1]
keys[2] corresponds to vals[2]
```

Then every time you call the `.load(indentifier)` function, you add a key to the `_keys` array, and at some point the `batchLoadingFn` is called, and is passed the `_keys` array as an argument.

The trick is... **How to call `.load(id)`** many times but with the `batchLoadingFn` only executed once? This is cool, and the reason I explored how this library works.

I found that it's possible to do this by specifying that `batchLoadingFn` is executed after a timeout, but that if `.load()` is called again before the timeout interval, then the timeout is canceled, a new key is added and a call to `batchLoadingFn` is rescheduled. Achieving this in code looks like so:

```
DataLoader.prototype.load = function(key) {
  clearTimeout(this._timer)
  this._timer = setTimeout(() => this.batchLoadingFn(), 0)
}
```

Essentially calling `.load()` deletes pending calls to `batchLoadingFn`, and then schedules a new call to `batchLoadingFn` at the back of the event loop. This guarantees that over a short space of time if `.load()` is called many times, `batchLoadingFn` will only be called once. This is actually very similar to **debouncing**. Or, at least it's useful when building websites and you want to do something on a `mousemove` event, but you get far more events than you want to deal with. I THINK this is called debouncing.

But calling `.load(key)` also needs to push a key to the `_keys` array, which we can in the body of the `.load` function by pushing the `key` argument to `_keys` (just `this._keys.push(key)`). However, the contract of the `.load` function is that it returns a single value pertaining to what the key argument resolves to. At some point the `batchLoadingFn` will be called and get a result (it has to return a result that corresponds to the `_keys`). Furthermore it's required that `batchLoadingFn` actually returns the promise of that value.

This next bit I thought was particularly clever (and well worth the effort of looking at the source code)!

The `dataloader` library, instead of keeping a list of keys in `_keys`, actually keeps a list of keys, associated with a reference to a `resolve` function, that when called results in a value being resolved as the result of `.load()`. `.load()` returns a promise, a promise is resolved when it's `resolve` function is invoked.

So the `_keys` array ACTUALLY keeps a list of `[key, resolve]` tuples. And when your `batchLoadingFn` returns, the `resolve` function is invoked with a value (that hopefully corresponds to the the item in the `_keys` array via index number).

So the `.load` function looks like this (in terms of pushing a `[key, resolve]` tuple to the `_keys` array):

```
DataLoader.prototype.load = function(key) {
  const promisedValue = new Promise ( resolve => this._keys.push({key, resolve}) )
  ...
  return promisedValue
}
```

And all that's left is to execute the `batchLoadingFn` with `_keys` keys as an argument, and invoke the correct `resolve` function on it's return

```
this._batchLoadingFn(this._keys.map(k => k.key))
  .then(values => {
    this._keys.forEach(({resolve}, i) => {
      resolve(values[i])
    })
    this._keys = [] // Reset for the next batch
  })
```

And combined, all the code to implement the above is here:

```
function DataLoader (_batchLoadingFn) {
  this._keys = []
  this._batchLoadingFn = _batchLoadingFn
}

DataLoader.prototype.load = function(key) {
  clearTimeout(this._timer)
  const promisedValue = new Promise ( resolve => this._keys.push({key, resolve}) )

  this._timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('You should only see me printed once!')
    this._batchLoadingFn(this._keys.map(k => k.key))
      .then(values => {
        this._keys.forEach(({resolve}, i) => {
          resolve(values[i])
        })
        this._keys = []
      })
  }, 0)

  return promisedValue
}

// Define a batch loading function
const batchLoadingFunction = keys => new Promise( resolve => resolve(keys.map(k => k * 2)) )

// Create a new DataLoader
const loader = new DataLoader(batchLoadingFunction)

// call .load() twice in quick succession
loader.load(1).then(result => console.log('Result with key = 1', result))
loader.load(2).then(result => console.log('Result with key = 2', result))
```

If I remember correctly I don't think the `dataloader` library uses `setTimeout`, and instead uses `process.nextTick`. But I couldn't get that to work.